# Facebook API Question

Tags: apache-flex, facebook

Hi I need a little help:
How to get profile URL given an UID?
Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just prepend this to UID:

`http://www.facebook.com/pages/profile/`

So it becomes:

`http://www.facebook.com/pages/profile/UID`